# FCM is not receiving by IOS device even if I am getting Successful response on server side

Tags: php, ios, swift

In PHP side I have created code to send FCM to IOS devices, I am passing accurate parameters here,When I try to send notification I am getting successful response like this

```
{
multicast_id: 6784314520531373000,
success: 2,
failure: 0,
canonical_ids: 0,
results: [
{
message_id: "0:1493995134709022%045ee4bf045ee4bf"
},
{
message_id: "0:1493995134709678%b71f17fbb71f17fb"
}
]
}
```

**[image removed]**

Bellow I posted my PHP code

```
function sendFcmIOS($urls, $registrationId) {

    // $ch = curl_init('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');

    $message = array('title' => 'FabPro1', 'URL' => $urls);

    //This array contains, the token and the notification. The 'to'
    attribute stores the token.
    //registration_ids 

    $arrayToSend = >array('registration_ids' => $registrationId, 'notification' => $message,
        'priority' => 'high');

//Generating JSON encoded string form the above array.  

    $json = json_encode($arrayToSend);

//Setup headers: 

    $headers = array();

    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';

    $headers[] = 'Authorization: key=*****';

//Setup curl, add headers and post parameters.   

    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);


    //Send the request  

    $response = curl_exec($ch);



    if ($response) {

        echo $response;
    } else {

        trigger_error(curl_error($ch));
        ;
    }

//Close request 

    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: You just posted your authorization key to the Internet. You should now consider it compromised, you'll want to deactivate it and create a new one immediately.

Comment: Also, please post your example code as text, not as images of text.

Comment: @AlexHownsky I have added my code here

Comment: Aaaaand you just posted your authorization key again....

Comment: Ohh, sorry I just forgot to erase that, But that was for testing only